# GitLab CI/CD downstream pipeline cannot be created - rules configuration prevents jobs from being added

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, continuous-deployment

I'm using GitLab CI/CD and I have a pipeline that includes a job from a separate configuration file, which has seemed to work ok. It looks like this:

`.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
  - triggers
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

trigger_infra:
  stage: triggers
  trigger:
    include: src/infra/.gitlab-ci.yml
  rules:
    - changes:
      - src/infra/lib/spa-stack.ts
```

`src/infra/.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
deploy_spa:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - cd src/spa
```

However, I recently ran into the following scenario:

1. Pushed code up that changed the `spa-stack.ts` file; build triggered and passed
2. Create merge request to master; build triggered and got an error!
3. Merged to master; build triggered and passed

The error message for the merge build was "downstream pipeline cannot be created, Pipeline will not run for the selected trigger. The rules configuration prevented any jobs from being added to the pipeline."

What am I missing here? The downstream job has no rules configurations on it AFAIK, so I feel like it should always just run, no questions asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, jobs do not run on merge request pipelines. That's why you have a problem with the downstream pipelines on merge requests.

To ensure the downstream pipeline works in both branch pipelines and pipelines for merge requests, you need to add `rules:` to the job (the rule itself doesn't matter much, but the mere presence of the `rules:` key will cause it to trigger on merge request pipelines).

```
deploy_spa:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - cd src/spa
  rules:
    - when: on_success
```

Comment: Confirmed that this works.  Thank you!

Comment: Relevant documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html